# create a new object w/ unique IDs and specific indeces

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I want a clean way to create a new object from the given data:

```js
const groups = [1, 2, null, 1, 1, null]
```

here is my target:

```js
// key = unique id, value = index of unique id in groups
const target = {
    null: [2, 5],
    1: [0, 3, 4],
    2: [1]
}
```

I try to reach:

1. the object keys of target are the unique entries of the groups array
2. to get the index of each value of the unique id and save them in an own array

---

my current approach:

```
const groupIDs = [1, 2, null, 1, 1, null]
const group = {}
const uniqueIDs = [...new Set(groupIDs)]
uniqueIDs.forEach(uid => {
  const arr = groupIDs.map((id, idx) => uid === id ? idx : null)
  const filtered = arr.filter(idx => idx !== null)
  Object.assign(group, { [uid]: filtered })
})
```

Comment: what does not work?

Comment: I'm searching for a clean way to reach the target. I hope it could be done in one or two loops.

Comment: What have you tried so far to reach your target?

Comment: @hindmost I just added my current approach. You can see that I am doing some unnecessary steps. I declare null to remove it in the next line. Seems strange to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reduce the array directly by using an object as accumulator and take the values as key and the indices as value for the grouped arrays.

This approach features an [logical nullish assignment `??=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) where the right side is assigned to the left, if the LHS is `undefined` or `null`.

```js
const
    groups = [1, 2, null, 1, 1, null],
    target = groups.reduce((r, value, index) => {
        r[value] ??= [];
        r[value].push(index);
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(target);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```